# d3.max didn't get the correct value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, max

I am using `d3.js` to render some data and the data set is a `csv` file called `bar-data.csv` like this:

```
date,value,duration
www.sina.com,53,100
www.baidu.com,165,2000
www.qq.com,269,690
www.youku.com,421,224
www.facebook.com,405,345
www.apple.com,376,777
www.cnn.com,359,298
www.cctv.com,433,333
www.google.com,455,500
www.boston.com,670,274
```

However when I using following codes to get the `maximum` of duration, the return value is `777` not `2000` (which should be the maximum among the data set).

```
d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = d.date;
    d.value = d.value;
});

var maximum = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.duration; });
alert ("max is " + maximum);
```

And if you change the `2000` to `999`, you will get the `999` as the maximum value. It seems that it only give out the answer with the same amount of digits.

What's the issue here?

Comment: can you show how you process the data? Tried doing this by converting the data you provided to an array of objects and passing it through the d3 max and I get max == 2000

Comment: @Alex_B Hi, please see the modified question... I provide more details. This is really weird.

Comment: within data.forEach try to add d.duration = d.duration, it should parse them correctly as integers

Comment: You can change "return d.duration;" to "return +d.duration;" to do the parseInt

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Changing the code to parse the duration values to Int fixes the problem together with processing them with d3.forEach function. See below:

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, data) {
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = d.date;
            d.value = d.value;
            d.duration = parseInt(d.duration);
        });

        var maximum = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.duration; });
        console.log("max is " + maximum);
    });
```

Thanks for the question I bet plenty of people have had this before!

Bye, Alex